# javascript: redirect to a page?

Tags: javascript

how do i use jquery [javascript] to goto another page?

or change the url in the browser urlfield and hit enter?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

nothing to do with jQuery, just this:

```
window.location.href = 'whatever.html';
```

Answer (score 4):

(Plain old javascript)

```
window.location = 'http://another-place.com';
```

Comment: @BipedalShark LOL. True but since jQuery has no method for doing this I think they're just going to have to step out of jQuery-world (as painful as that is I admit) sometimes. :)

Comment: @Darrell, I guess `$(window).attr("location", "http://another.com")` might work.. but what a waste of function calls... haha!