# show popup during page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

i have a requirement to show javascript Ok/Cancel option on page load. So, when the user is redirected from the previous page to this page, based on some logic in the query string, we have to display javascript OK/Cancel (page is not yet rendered here). Once the user clicks, we have to load different type of data (server side execution) based on OK/Cancel. what is the best way of accomplishing this task? thanks.

Comment: What happens if the user has Javascript disabled?

Comment: Good point Dan. instead of the OK/Cancel stuff, have you (user583126) considered a < noscript > solution?

Comment: @Andbdrew: What is the <noscript> solution? it is also ok for us to use jquery instead of javascript ok/cancel. basically, we want to execute something on the server side based on what is selected on the client side.

Comment: @user583126 <noscript> allows authors to define alternate content to render for users with javascript disabled. jQuery is a javascript framework, so there is no 'instead' here.

Comment: @user583126 html inside a <noscript> tag will be rendered on the page only if javascript is disabled in the user's browser. yeah, what Dan said about jQuery and Javascript.

Comment: ok, I understood the noscript thing. But how do i accomplish my task. Let's assume that JS is always enabled!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the various problems with this requirement, here's the simplest approach that I can think of.

1. Create an HTML page with no content
2. Execute the following in Javascript:

   1. [Grab and parse the querystring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-querystring-values-in-javascript)
   2. Based on the querystring, determine which URL you would like to redirect the user to
   3. [Use `confirm()` to determine the course of action](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.confirm)
   4. [Change the window location to your new page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854308/javascript-redirect-to-a-page)

[Your `<noscript>` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html40/interact/scripts.html) should contain directions on what a user who has javascript disabled should do... something more helpful than '*Please enable javascript*' would be nice, but it's your call.

Answer (score 0):

Load a small html page stub with basic formatting, then popup your dialog box.

Depending on the response, populate the page's contents using an ajax request.

Here's some very basic example code. See [this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp) for examples of how to make an Ajax call in javascript.

```
<html>
  <head><!-- Head Contents --></head>
  <body>
    <!-- Basic body styling -->

    <noscript>This page works best with scripts enabled</noscript>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      // Show Dialog Box
      if(option1) {
        // Do Ajax call
        // Set page contents 
      } elsif (option2) {
        // Do other ajax call
        // Set page contents 
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I know this won't work with JavaScript disabled, but its answering the asker's question directly

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla popping up a dialog:

```
if (confirm("Your question")) 
{ 
    // do things if OK
}
```

Although you should look into the other answers/comments here, as this will break if the user has disabled javascript.

*Edit*: If you want to load more info after the dialog, you will have to use ajax. Since your answer is quite general, I can only point you in the direction of the [jQuery ajax functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) for now.

Comment: this will execute after your server side events are all executed for the page! I am looking for page events to continue execution after 'something' has happened on the client side.

Comment: Then you'd have to use ajax to fetch more info after the dialog. I'll edit the answer to add some information on this.