# Header(location: ...) not completely working in webview on android

Tags: php, android, webview, http-headers

I've created an online store within an android app in webview but have one major problem...

When im processing my shopping cart i go to a php file, save the items in a session variable and then use the following to bounce back to the page i was just on...

```
Header('Location:' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

This works perfectly on the android browser but unfortunately does not work in webview... Does anyone know how fix or a workaround for this please

One thing is though that it does work if i specify a location such as

```
Header('Location: shop.php');
```

So it seems that its $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] which does not work... can anyone help with a work around please...

Comment: `Header('Location: shop.php');` is wrong, location headers need to use [absolute URIs](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all browsers send a 'referer' string with the request, I suspect webview is one of these.

You should include the url the previous page was on within the form that you submitted, then you can use this.

Answer (score 1):

This are two ways which could work for you:

1. Use a [Javascript Redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854308/javascript-redirect-to-a-page#1854313):
   `<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href = "url";</script>`
2. Use a [HTML Meta Tag](http://webdesign.about.com/od/metataglibraries/a/aa080300a.htm):
   `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://webdesign.about.com/">`

Those two examples can also be called later than just before the first script output. But remember that not all clients support this.